# Scrapy Increase robustness when scraping

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying my best to search for a setting on the Scrapy spider
when the following condition occurs.

1. In the middle of my scraping activity If I have a power failure
2. my ISP goes down

and the behavior i am expecting is Scrapy should not give up.
rather wait infinitely for power to be restored and continue scraping by retrying the requests after a brief pause or interval of 10secs.

This is the error message that i get when my internet goes off.

```
 https://example.com/1.html
 2022-10-21 17:44:14 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying 
 <GET https://www.example.com/1.html
 (failed 1 times): An error occurred while connecting: 10065: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host..
```

And the message repeats.

what i am afraid is when the blip is restored scrapy would have given up trying 1.html and might have gone to another url called 99.html.

My question is when the error socket operation to an unreachable host occurs how to make scrapy wait and retry the same url https://www.example.com/1.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error you receive when the this happens?

Comment: Hi Alexander thanks a lot for taking a peek at this question and this is the error i get  (failed 1 times): An error occurred while connecting: 10065: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host..

Comment: For that I think you may have to reimplement the RetryMiddleware and pretty much do the same process I do below but instead catch the exception instead of listening for 404 errors.

Comment: Alexander thank you so much I am thankful for both the answer's from you .You managed to read my next question and somehow answered it via telepathy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in setting that will do this, however this can still be implemented rather easily.

The way that seems the most straight forward to me would be to catch the `response_received` signal in your spider and check for the specific error code you receive when your ISP goes down.  When this happens you can pause the scrapy engine and wait for any amount of time you want and then retry that same request again, until it succeeds.

for example:

```py
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.signals import response_received

class MySpider(Spider):
   ...
   ...

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        # listen for the response_received signal and call check_response
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.check_response, signal=response_received)
        return spider

    def check_response(self, response, request, spider):
        engine = spider.crawler.engine
        if response.status == 404:  # <- your error code goes here
            engine.pause()
            time.sleep(6000)        # <- wait 10 minutes
            request.dont_filter = True   # <- tell engine not to filter
            engine.unpause()
            engine.crawl(request.copy())  # <- resend the request
```

---

Update

Since it isn't an http error code you are receiving the next best solution would be to create a custom `DownloaderMiddleware` that catches the exceptions and then pretty much does the same thing that is done in the first example.

In your `middlewares.py` file:

```py
import time
from twisted.internet.error import (ConnectError, ConnectionLost
                                    TimeoutError, DNSLookupError,
                                    ConnectionRefusedError)

class ConnectionLostPauseDownloadMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, settings, crawler):
        self.crawler = crawler
        self.exceptions = (ConnectionRefusedError, ConnectionDone, ConnectError, ConnectionLost)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.settings, crawler)

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        if isinstance(exception, self.exceptions):
            new_request = request.copy()
            new_request.dont_filter = True
            self.crawler.engine.pause()
            time.sleep(60 * 10)
            self.crawler.engine.unpause()
            return new_request
```

Then in your `settings.py`

```py
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'MyProjectName.middlewares.ConnectionLostPauseDownloadMiddleware': 543,
}
```

Comment: Hmm i have error message of Unreachable host before Scrapy i used the nice python library called Tenacity.

Comment: Hi Alexander my apologies this is the library i used to decorate my python method or function https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ so it keeps retrying When i have a network error.

Comment: You have used response.status = 404 but in my case when the network fails I will have 10065: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host.So how do we retry using your check response callback please.

Comment: I am unable to figure out a solution but your code looks promising Only question I have with respect to your code is what should i use instead of if response.status == 404: in your check response method.Since during a network error i will have a socket timeout error.

Comment: @asfandhikmat  okay... so what is the `tenacity` library do for you then? Can you please edit your question to include the type of exception that is thrown?  If you don't know then pasting the full error message  and traceback would work as well

Comment: When i was not using scrapy and used to scrape pages, I would decorate my function that made a request to the webpage and if i sent a request that resulted in a failure that library can retry my request.